# Session changed

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

Website set at company server, and use the session to store user information like user account & name. I wrote the session on the login page and never rewrote it, but the client pc has an account changing problem as user A in the middle of operating his account will change to user B maybe while user B logs in. User A and User B are on the same Intranet and use different PC.

Is the session make this problem? How to solve this problem modify code less?

Comment: Is the application pool for the site set to use more than one worker process (a "web garden")? In "Advanced settings", it's "Maximum worker processes". That can cause that problem. [Web gardens... are they good or bad or what?](https://serverfault.com/q/81689/109573)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have two rather seperate issues.

First the user - can logon with different logons. That in fact should give them each seperate sesisons. Perhaps you not logging out the user correctly when they logoff. (or maybe you rolled your own logon system - bad idea!! - since now you can and will have a session probem.

Next up:
You have to adopt a design in which session() allows the ONE user to work, and work if they right click - new tab, or even launch another copy of the web browser. So, you have to be REALLY careful here. Say a user clicks on a gridview - typical select some project, product or whatever. So you shove the PK id of that selected row into session, and then of course jump to a new page.

but, if they have two tabs open, or two browsers open on that grid? Well, now they can click on one copy, select row, jump to new page. Then the user does the same on the other grid.

Now, your PK session ID is DIFFERENT for the first page. If that code continues to use session() for that information, you are in BIG trouble!!!  - the PK id in session on the first page is now different, and not the PK the user selected.

So, what to do in above? well, there is a hodge podge of workarounds - some add a custom number to some session value - some add a number to the URL - all are quite messey.

The simple soluion? Adopet a coding practice that you ONLY use session() to pass values, but on first page load, you transfer that to ViewState. View state is per page, (or per tab, or per browser page). Session() of course is global to user.

So, if they pick a house to buy from that grid, jump to a new page. Now they do the same on the 2nd browser copy - they are sitting on two different houses, but your session PK value is different!!! If they click buy or any other kind of operations on the first page? That code can NOT use session() anymore, can it?

So, even when I have say 4-5 values i must pass to the next page via session? I on page load  (is postback = false), transfer those values to ViewState. You now write ALL CODE ON that page to ALWAYS use ViewState, and thus session() values never trip over each other. Two web pages on the same grid, user clicks - pass via session, transfer to viewstate. So, now you don't care.

And the above approch would solve your probelm at least of passing values. However, I see VERY little reason to store user information in session(). That is what the membership, and roles and the logon system does for you, and thus, if they logon with different ID, then membership GetUserID etc. should and will return a correct user ID. So, while the above design pattern will solve the tripping over PK and vaues passed around, it will not solve your session informaton that you have for the user. But as I stated, you REALLY do not, and should not need to store user logon information in session anyway.

however if you do correctly need and let a user change/flip/jump to a new different logon? If you first logout the user, then session can and should start over - it not clear how you logout the user, but I would look at that code.

I use this to logout a user:

```
        Session.Abandon()

        FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
```

So the above should start a new session - even if you allow user to flip, or change or logon to a different user.

However, the general over all issue of the session? Your problem is not only user session information, but that using session() values in general code - be careful, and always ask if the values in session() are ok to be used if the user say had 2 or 5 copies of the browser open.

Comment: I use Session.Clear() and FormsAuthentication.SignOut() to logout a user and write it at master page. Surely users log in with the same browser different tabs will make user changed, but users log in with different PC.

Comment: I would add the session.Abandon() to above. Clearing a session can still keep it active, so do both. As for the comments about session()? Just pointing out some issues if users right click or have multiple tabs open - you have to be carful.